# Could my dad still have Dutch nationality

Tags: residency

My dad and grandparents were all born in Amsterdam but in 1962 his parents immigrated to Rhodesia where they obtain Rhodesian nationality.
Would he be able to regain his Dutch nationality now even if he hasn't had a Dutch passport of his own?

Comment: It's very unlikely.  It's possible that he retained his Dutch nationality initially, depending on the circumstances of his parents' and his naturalization in Rhodesia, but if that's true then he most likely lost his Dutch nationality in 2013, 10 years after the change in the 10-year rule. There are exceptions to the 10-year rule depending on where he was living and who he was married to, if anyone, but these are unlikely to apply.  He probably is eligible for the simplified procedure for former Dutch nationals, but that requires having a Dutch residence permit if I recall correctly.

Comment: However, if he retained his Dutch nationality and you were over 18 in 2013 and are now under 28 then you might be Dutch, so it might be worthwhile for you to go into the details.

Comment: Were your grandparents Dutch citizens when your Dad was born in the Netherlands, or which status did they have? (All this to first find out what his status was exactly when he left the Netherlands). When your Dad's parents moved to Rhodesia, did your Dad go with them? In that case, did they apply for Rhodesian citizenship for him, and did he get it? At which age did he get it? Or did he apply himself as an adult? (All this to found out how his status changed). Where is your Dad now? In the Netherlands, in the EU, or where else? It would be worthwhile to contact the local register if he is in t